# How to check object in model class when its null sometime in response in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Error is shown when subscription object is null which is the required type parameter.

Error: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

How to solve this error, arrived on when subscription object is null.

I also shared my model class download link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gcOKQ49RaEF3w0NBPpijGtbGUdSkgZrx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try like `List.from(json['futureClasses']??[])`

Comment: Not sure, class is too big.  You can try like `json['futureClasses']as List? ??[]` inside `from`

Comment: i have problem in Subscription object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try with this

```
if(json['subscription'] !=null) { subscription = Subscription.fromJson(json['subscription']); }
```